# How to stream/play video but prevent saving?

Tags: video, stream, video-streaming

I'm in planing for lunching an online training website.

In our website we will put many video files and users should have premium account to watch our videos.

Our challenge is saving video files by users, we don't want users can save our videos and they should watch online, so we want stream our videos so users cannot save the video files, is there any better solution for this challenge ? what should we do for streaming ? because YouTube videos are stream too but users can save YouTube videos.

Comment: @pst I removed YouTube tag

Comment: This will likely require a custom player (or better, an existing player) that supports end-point encryption. Good luck! (And the user could always record the video with a hand cam :-)

Answer (score 0):

Look at flow player or jwplayer and flash RTMP streaming. You can further look at DRM, signed URls etc.